# MYSQL: Find rows where multiple ID match

Tags: php, mysql, relational-division

I have a table setup similarly as below.

```
genre_id  series_id
1         4
1         2
2         5
4         1
2         4
3         3
```

What I want to do is to be able to find all series based on the mix of genres selected.

For example finding all series that have a genre id of 1 and 2. Hypothetically the result I want is the series ID of 4.

If I use

```
SELECT series_id FROM table WHERE genre_id = 1 AND genre_id = 2
```

it returns nothing.

If I use

```
SELECT series_id FROM table WHERE genre_id in (1, 2)
```

it returns everything in 1 and 2. But I just want the rows where the genre_id's intersect.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT series_id FROM table
WHERE genre_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY series_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Note this is assuming that the pair (genre_id, series_id) is unique. If it is not you will have to change the `HAVING` clause to

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT genre_id) = 2
```

Also note that the number `2` in the `HAVING` clause must match the amount of items in the `IN` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the `IN()` predicate as basically a series of `OR` terms; it's equivalent to

```
SELECT series_id
FROM MyTable 
WHERE genre_id = 1 OR genre_id = 2
```

What you want is to turn the `OR` into `AND`, but that doesn't make any sense because a WHERE expression applies to *one row at a time.* There's no way genre_id can be both 1 *and* 2 on the same row.

So you need to compare genre_id from two different rows in one expression. You can do this by joining the two rows:

```
SELECT t1.series_id
FROM MyTable AS t1
INNER JOIN MyTable AS t2 USING (series_id)
WHERE t1.genre_id = 1 AND t2.genre_id = 2
```

There's also a solution using GROUP BY as shown in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20341132/20860), but the self-join can be orders of magnitude more efficient if you define the right indexes.

I describe more details for this solution in my presentation [SQL Query Patterns, Optimized](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-query-patterns-optimized).

Comment: So if I had lets say n genre_ids to match for series_ids, would there be an elegant way of doing it, instead of doing n amount of joins?

Comment: You'll need n joins. The more efficient way of achieving a query isn't necessarily the one that is written in the fewest characters.